# How to add a regular page under a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, hierarchical

I'm building a WordPress website that should have the following structure:

- Project A (project post type)

  - About (regular page)
  - Location (regular page)
  - Partners (regular page)
  - News (regular page)
- Project B (project post type)

  - About (regular page)
  - Book (regular page)

As you see, each project can have random pages below it. The admin should be able to add any page as he wants.

I found some solutions based on setting the `hierarchical` attribute from my custom post type to `true` and making it supports `page-attributes`. Those don't fit my needs because it'll only make possible to add a **project** under another **project**.

There is a way to do what I need?

Comment: If these are only few projects, what about using the navigational menu UI to create this structure? There you can mix it at will.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are dozens of projects. However, now you mentioned, I may create a menu just to hold all projects hierarchy (instead of a menu for each project), but not display it in the front-end. Only use it as a guide for the structure. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Another approach might be a custom project taxonomy to store the relationships.

Comment: What about a piece of custom meta that you could use to set a "project post type" as the parent.

Comment: On the menu approach, I've just realized that if I have an **About** page for each project, for example, the slug will become `about`, `about-2`, `about-3` and so on. Also, it doesn't cover the URL structure. I won't have something like `/project-a/about`, by simply using the menu as the guide for hierarchy.

Comment: @GentlemanMax, yea, this is a way to do that. I'd prefer to use WordPress' native hierarchy functionality, but maybe it's not possible. So adding a meta box where I can choose the parent project for a single page should work. Then, in the back-end I may fix the slug/URL, right?

Comment: @GustavoStraube, yes.  You'll need to create a custom rewrite schema using https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule.  I would populate the meta box with a dropdown select and have each option represent a page in the database.

Comment: Add your suggestion to an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this (from [Post parent of different type](http://janina.tumblr.com/post/3588081423/post-parent-different-type)):

> I was thrilled to find out what I could do with WordPress Custom Post
>   Types, but very much underwhelmed that you weren’t able to set the
>   parent of a post to be a post of a different type. That is, say you’ve
>   created a custom post type “Chapter”, you couldn’t set the parent of a
>   “Chapter” post to be a “Part” post. The parent had to be of the same
>   type.
>
> I’ve found a simple workaround which essentially replaces the
>   “restriction” WP puts on the parent type. Besides the meta box on the
>   edit post page, there are actually no restrictions on what post type
>   the parent may be.
>
> ```
> add_action( 'admin_menu', function() { 
>   remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv', 'chapter', 'normal' ); } );
> add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() { add_meta_box( 
>   'chapter-parent', 'Part', 'chapter_attributes_meta_box', 'chapter', 'side', 'high'); } );
>
> function chapter_attributes_meta_box( $post ) {
>   $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
>   if ( $post_type_object->hierarchical ) {
>       $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array(
>           'post_type' => 'part', 
>           'selected' => $post->post_parent, 
>           'name' => 'parent_id', 
>           'show_option_none' => __( '(no parent)' ), 
>           'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 
>           'echo' => 0
>       ) );
>       if ( ! empty( $pages ) ) {
>           echo $pages;
>       } // end empty pages check
>   } // end hierarchical check
> }
> ```